# Return a requests.Response object from Flask

Tags: python, proxy, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to build a simple proxy using Flask and requests. The code is as follows:

```
@app.route('/es/<string:index>/<string:type>/<string:id>',
           methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT']):
def es(index, type, id):
    elasticsearch = find_out_where_elasticsearch_lives()
    # also handle some authentication
    url = '%s%s%s%s' % (elasticsearch, index, type, id)

    esreq = requests.Request(method=request.method, url=url,
                             headers=request.headers, data=request.data)
    resp = requests.Session().send(esreq.prepare())
    return resp.text
```

This works, except that it loses the status code from Elasticsearch. I tried returning `resp` (a `requests.models.Response`) directly, but this fails with

```
TypeError: 'Response' object is not callable
```

Is there another, simple, way to return a `requests.models.Response` from Flask?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Ok, found it:

> If a tuple is returned the items in the tuple can provide extra information. Such tuples have to be in the form (response, status, headers). The status value will override the status code and headers can be a list or dictionary of additional header values.

([Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#about-responses).)

So

```
return resp.content, resp.status_code, resp.headers.items()
```

seems to do the trick.

Comment: use `resp.content` instead of `resp.text` to handle both binary and text responses

Comment: There is no need for parenthesis around the returned value.

Comment: I still get "Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it"... any guidance?

Answer (score 20):

Using `text` or `content` property of the [`Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) object will not work if the server returns encoded data (such as `content-encoding: gzip`) and you return the headers unchanged. This happens because `text` and `content` have been decoded, so there will be a mismatch between the header-reported encoding and the actual encoding.

According to [the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content):

> In the rare case that you’d like to get the raw socket response from the server, you can access `r.raw`. If you want to do this, make sure you set `stream=True` in your initial request.

and

> `Response.raw` is a raw stream of bytes – it does not transform the response content.

So, the following works for gzipped data too:

```
esreq = requests.Request(method=request.method, url=url,
                         headers=request.headers, data=request.data)
resp = requests.Session().send(esreq.prepare(), stream=True)
return resp.raw.read(), resp.status_code, resp.headers.items()
```

If you use a shortcut method such as `get`, it's just:

```
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
return resp.raw.read(), resp.status_code, resp.headers.items()
```

Comment: This is the approach that I decided on. However, I found that I had to pop the `Transfer-Encoding` item from the response headers. I get an error if I don't: "The response headers can't include 'Content-Length' with chunked encoding"

Answer (score 2):

Flask can return an object of type `flask.wrappers.Response`.

You can create one of these from your `requests.models.Response` object `r` like this:

```
from flask import Response

return Response(
    response=r.reason,
    status=r.status_code,
    headers=dict(r.headers)
)
```

Comment: What should be the value of `r.reason`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same scenario, except that in my case my requests.models.Response contained an attachment. This is how I got it to work:

> return send_file(BytesIO(result.content), mimetype=result.headers['Content-Type'], as_attachment=True)

Comment: Thanks! This solved also my problems with headers (which somehow created a CORS problem)

Answer (score 0):

My use case is to call another API in my own Flask API. I'm just propagating unsuccessful `requests.get` calls through my Flask response. Here's my successful approach:

```py
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer Muh Token'
}
try:
    response = requests.get(
        '{domain}/users/{id}'\
            .format(domain=USERS_API_URL, id=hit['id']),
        headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError as err:
    logging.error(err)
    flask.abort(flask.Response(response=response.content, status=response.status_code, headers=response.headers.items()))
```