# Flask remote authentication issue with Graphite

Tags: python-requests, graphite

I have a Flask app which sends a request to a Graphite server to authenticate and redirect to it's dashboard (changed setting REMOTE_USER_AUTHENTICATION = True). The request is as follows:

```
url = 'https://graphite.localdomain/dashboard'
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, auth=('userx', 'passwordx'),verify=False)
print r.cookies.__dict__
return (r.text, r.status_code, r.headers.items())
```

The authentication from the request to the graphite server is good, I get 200's for valid users, and 401's for invalid users.

"print r.cookies.__dict__" will output...

```
{'_now': 1429303134, '_policy': <cookielib.DefaultCookiePolicy instance
at 0x7f263ec2b638>, '_cookies': {'graphite.localdomain': {'/':
{'sessionid': Cookie(version=0, name='sessionid',
value='**********masked**********', port=None, port_specified=False,
domain='graphite.localdomain', domain_specified=False,
domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False,
expires=1430512734, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None,
rest={'httponly': None}, rfc2109=False)}}}, '_cookies_lock': <_RLock
owner=None count=0>}
```

...which appears right because it looks identical to the one I get from logging in directly to Graphite. But, when I return the response object ([Return a requests.Response object from Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568950/return-a-requests-response-object-from-flask)) the browser returns content encoding errors in both Chrome and FireFox. If I change that to something like...

```
return r.content
```

...the dashboard page appears, but it's missing everything because the CSS and JS resources are 404'ing.

I am obviously not understanding something, any help would be greatly appreciated.