# mailgun and flask forms

Tags: flask, mailgun, flask-wtforms

I keep getting the following error when I run my code:

TypeError: 'Response' object is not callable

Here is my code...

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash
import os
import requests

import forms

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'jfdsjajfjds'

mg_key = os.environ['MAILGUN_API_KEY']

@app.route("/", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def landing():
    form = forms.OptinForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return requests.post(
            "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/test_list@sandbox.mailgun.org/members",
            auth=('api', 'mg_key'),
            data={'subscribed': True,
                  'address': form.email.data,
                  'name': form.first_name.data})
    flash("Thanks! Check your email.")
    return render_template('landing.html', form=form)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a requests.Response object from Flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568950/return-a-requests-response-object-from-flask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was calling my API key variable as a string. fixed it by changing 'mg_key' to mg_key