# Prettify Json response in Swagger UI

Tags: json, httpresponse, swagger-ui, pretty-print

Is there a way of prettifying JSON in response bodies in Swagger UI?
I'm using SwaggerUIBundle.

Comment: Try Wirespec instead. It is way better than Swagger and has built-in formatting for JSON. https://wirespec.dev

Comment: I believe Swagger UI pretty-prints JSON responses by default. Is your response actually `Content-Type: application/json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My API was returning text content for `Content-Type`. Using Flask as a proxy and was only returning the content of the `requests` response. This SO post helped [Return a requests.Response object from Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568950/return-a-requests-response-object-from-flask)

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing on [Marko's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65396303/4427457), in C# you can do 2 things:

1. Decorate the method with:

   [Produces("application/json")]
2. Use a Json() or JsonResult():

   return base.Ok(new JsonResult(response));